# Map county borders on to a ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I am generating a few maps and I would like show the borders of counties on top of a `ggmap` roadmap.  Here is an example using part of Texas.

```
library(ggmap)
map = get_map(location = c(-95.31619, 28.42460), 
              zoom = 6, source = "google", maptype="roadmap")
map.plot = ggmap(map)

# get texas counties
counties <- map_data("county")
tx_county <- subset(counties, region == 'texas')

map.plot + 
  theme_nothing() + 
  geom_polygon(data = tx_county, aes(x=long, y=lat), fill = NA, color = "red")
```

However, the resulting figure has lines crossing counties instead of just the borders.

[image]

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?  I have seen another example [here](http://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html) where it works when only using `ggplot2` but I would like to use the 'roadmap' from `ggmap`.

Comment: You could try either [A] `download.file("http://www.clipartlord.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/cat61-217x240.png", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".png"), mode="wb"); map.plot + geom_polygon(data = tx_county, aes(x=long, y=lat), fill = NA, color = "red") + coord_cartesian() + annotation_custom(g<-grid::rasterGrob(img<-png::readPNG(tf)), xmin=-98.489382, xmax=-93.841921, ymin=25.123596, ymax=27.698022) 
` or you could try [B] `map.plot + geom_polygon(data = tx_county, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), fill = NA, color = "red")`. I like A. :)

Comment: @lukeA, I would like to do something a little more standard than finding another file online to stick in.  The code I provided is concise within R but I don't know why I get the lines crossing county boundaries.

Comment: @lukeA Ah, the B option (which I overlooked) does it.  Not sure why the `group` is needed but that fixes the problem.  If you post answer below I will accept.

Comment: done. [A] was just a joke, couldn't resist when I saw that ball of wool ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the grouping for the polygons:

```
map.plot + 
  geom_polygon(data = tx_county, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), fill = NA, color = "red")
```