# Overlay region borders in R map generates unwanted lines

Tags: r

I have already generated a simple map for Nigerian states, and now I would like to highlight in my map the borders for the Nigerian regions (that group Nigerian states). 
When I add the layer for the borders with geom_polygon, they appear lines that do not correspond to region borders. I found a similar problem here  [Map county borders on to a ggmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155672/map-county-borders-on-to-a-ggmap) 
 but this does not seem to be working for my case.

Here are the shapefiles and the database I am working on:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cek92s50jixowfx/AABwIVZKvtff8-9slhfCbxEca?dl=0

The code I am using is

```
#LOAD SHAPEFILES AND DATABASE 
ng_dist <- readShapeSpatial("NGA_adm1.shp")
ng_dist_regions <- readShapeSpatial("NGA_adm_Region.shp")
NG_States <- read.csv("State_color_map.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")

#VERIFY THE MAPS LOADED PROPERLY
plot(ng_dist)
plot(ng_dist_regions)

# STATE MAP - fortify and match shapefile and database IDs names

intersect(ng_dist$NAME_1, NG_States$STATE)
ng_dist <- fortify(ng_dist, region = "NAME_1")

ng_dist$id[which(ng_dist$id == "Akwa Ibom")] <- "Akwa-ibom"
ng_dist$id[which(ng_dist$id == "Nassarawa")] <- "Nasarawa"
ng_dist$id[which(ng_dist$id == "Cross River")] <- "C/river"
ng_dist$id[which(ng_dist$id == "Federal Capital Territory")] <- "FCT"

intersect(ng_dist$id, NG_States$STATE)


# REGION MAP - fortify
ng_dist_regions <- fortify(ng_dist_regions, region = "Region")


### Convert dummy variable to factor

NG_States$Abia <- as.factor(NG_States$Abia)


#PLOT MAP with coloured Abia State

cols <- c("0" = "#e6e6e6","1" = "#6eab27")

ABIA <- NG_States$Abia

Abia_map <- ggplot(NG_States, aes(fill = ABIA)) + 
  geom_map(data = NG_States, aes(map_id = NG_States$STATE, fill = ABIA), map = ng_dist, color = "black", size = 0.10) + 
  expand_limits(x = ng_dist$long, y = ng_dist$lat) +  
  theme_nothing(legend = FALSE) +
  labs(title="Abia") +
  coord_map() + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values=cols, labels=c("","Abia"))

Abia_map 

#Add layer for region borders

d <- Abia_map +   
   geom_polygon(aes(x = ng_dist_regions$long, y = ng_dist_regions$lat, group = ng_dist_regions$id, fill = NA), data = ng_dist_regions, color = "red", size = 0.8) 

d
```

Here is my result

[Nigerian States and Regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CPw9.png)

I have tried to add other options, such as `coord_fixed()` or `expand_limits(x = ng_dist_regions$long, y = ng_dist_regions$lat)`, but I am quite basic R user and I don't know other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `group`, instead of `id` as group seems to solve the problem.

```
d <- Abia_map +   
  geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = ng_dist_regions, color = "red", size = 0.8, inherit.aes = FALSE) 
d
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! The code is working perfectly now, even if my map looks a bit different (but this https://www.dropbox.com/s/cy70jmre9qia2nc/Rplot.png?dl=0  is exactly what I wanted)