# Unable To Overlay Counties On Geographic Map In R?

Tags: r, google-maps, heatmap, ggmap

I am trying to use the code that was presented [in an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155672/map-county-borders-on-to-a-ggmap) to generate a map of Minnesota including its counties.

While I am able to generate a map of Minnesota with the following code:

```
Minnesota<-get_map(location = "Minnesota", 
               zoom = 6, source = "google", maptype="roadmap")
```

[image]
I am not able to generate a breakdown of counties with the following code though:

```
##Get Minnesota Counties
    counties <- map_data("county")
    mn_county <- subset(counties, region == 'minnesota')
    Minnesota + 
      geom_polygon(data = mn_county, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), fill = NA, color = "red")
```

Instead of getting a map with county outlines, I get the following error message:

```
Error in Minnesota + geom_polygon(data = mn_county, aes(x = long, y = lat,  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.raster", "+.gg") for "+"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ggmap(Minnesota)` to map the base_layer:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

Minnesota<-get_map(location = "Minnesota", 
                   zoom = 6, source = "google", maptype="roadmap")

##Get Minnesota Counties
counties <- map_data("county")
mn_county <- subset(counties, region == 'minnesota')
ggmap(Minnesota) + 
  geom_polygon(data = mn_county, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), fill = NA, color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>